# Issue with special characters

Tags: python, json, ajax, unicode

I am facing an issue where special characters are not being printed properly on my webpage.

So, I am making an ajax query, with python script at backend :

```
$.ajax({                                                                       
    url: BACK_END_LOC + 'get_search_results',                                  
    data: ({keyword1: keyword1,                                                
            keyword2: keyword2,                                                
            start_time: encodeURI(start_time),                                 
            end_time: encodeURI(end_time),                                     
            dataset: $("#dataset").val()                                       
            }),                                                                

    success: function(data) {                                                  
        response = eval('(' + data + ')');                                     
        if (response.error_code == 0) {                                        
            render_event_search_results(response.data);                        
        } else {                                                               
        alert('Error_code:' + response.error_code + ', Error_msg:' + response.error_msg);
        }                                                                      
    },
```

Python is returning a json object:

```
def get_search_results(req, keyword1, keyword2, start_time, end_time, dataset):
s = keyword1 + "," + keyword2

# get filtered events
results = get_filtered_events(dataset, keyword1, keyword2, start_time, end_time)

try:
    r = {'error_code': 0, 'error_msg': 'OK', 'data': results}

except Exception, e:
    raise e
    r = {'error_code': 1, 'error_msg': 'Oops'}

return simplejson.dumps(r)
```

Now, one field of this object has special characters. When I try to print this field on html "alert(gEvents[0].signature)", it is being printed as : \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043e_storm

How can I get it printed like :видео_storm, which is the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return simplejson.dumps(r)
```

with

```
return simplejson.dumps(r,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, though it worked with signature_str.decode('unicode-escape').